# Does the letter C serve any unique purpose?

Tags: pronunciation, alphabet

Does the letter 'C' make any sound that cannot be made by other letters?

"Cat" could be spelled "Kat," "Cinder" could be spelled "Sinder," and "Watch" could be spelled "Watsh."

---

**Edit:**

An excerpt from a comment by Kosmonaut:

> There is no difference between ["ch" and "tch"]; both
>   are /tʃ/. Thus, "witch" and "which"
>   are pronounced exactly the same:
>   [wɪtʃ]. (Actually some Southern
>   American dialects pronounce "which" as
>   [ʍɪtʃ], but that is only a difference
>   in the "w" sound, not the /tʃ/.)

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Pronouncing the English alphabet](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/pronunciation-of-the-english-alphabet)

Comment: Spelling reform plan: http://www.ojohaven.com/fun/spelling.html

Comment: @z7sg: you should [sign my petition](http://www.sultanik.com/Or%C3%BEography_for_dental_fricatives)!  ;-)

Comment: I'm sure this duplicates (or at least closely parallels) another question, but I'm blowed if I can find it.  Grr.

Comment: @Esu Dude, lighthouse is properly pronounced light-house

Comment: @Rhodri: Wasn't it a question about the letter _X_?

Comment: @Rhodri @Callithumpian: You may be referring to [this question about X](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19493/why-is-x-used-when-we-pronounce-it-z)

Comment: Suppose that we're eliminating "C", how do you propose we spell "chair"?

Comment: There's also the /ts/ sound of "once" and "hence".

Comment: @z7sg: Exactly my point: It has "th" (if you don't hyphenate it), yet it is pronounced as the voiceless alveolar plosive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not a bad remark.

- **All Germanic cognates of *cat* are indeed spelled with a 'k'** (from P.Gmc. *kattuz, O.Fris. katte, O.N. köttr, Du. kat, O.H.G. kazza, Ger. Katze). The English word is spelled with a 'c' under the influence of Late Latin (cattus).  See **step 3** below.
- **All Germanic cognates of *cinder* are indeed spelled with an 's'**: P.Gmc. *sindran (cf. O.S. sinder, O.N. sindr, M.L.G., M.Du. sinder, O.H.G. sintar, Ger. Sinter.  Initial s- changed to c- under influence of Fr. cendre "ashes.  See **step 4** below.

The letter 'C' has already disappeared from a lot of words.

Here are a few examples of the evolution of the spelling of some Old English words.

- *queen* used to be spelled *cwen* (and mean "young woman").
- *quick* used to be spelled *cwic* (and mean alive).
- *drink* used to be spelled *drinc*.
- *bishop* used to be spelled *biscop* (closer to "Episcopal").
- *ship* used to be spelled *scip*.

Of course there is no single cause to all these changes.  And even summarising them in a small answer is a huge challenge.

But there is an interesting section in the [wikipedia article about the 'C' letter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C#Later_use).

Yet I'd like to add a few background considerations.

1. After the Anglo Saxon conquest of Britain in the 5th century, texts (very few have actually come down to us) were all written in the [Runic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runic_alphabet), because that was the alphabet in use in Germany (it had actually been borrowed from the Etruscan who add taken it from the Greeks who... who... Proto-Canaanite/Egyptians).  In other words the Latin alphabet introduced by the Roman occupation fell into complete oblivion.
2. When [Pope Gregory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_I) sent out [Augustine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustine_of_Canterbury) to convert the famously <sup>"*[non angli, sed angeli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_Angli,_sed_Angeli#Famous_quotes_and_anecdotes)*"</sup> heathens, the dominant writing system shifted back to the Latin alphabet.  Within a few decades England quickly raised to the most culturally prominent country in Europe (its lavishly illuminated Bibles and other religious manuscripts can still be found in many European museums and libraries).  But the language used for these masterpieces was *still* Latin.  There are very few words of English in these texts.
3. Then the Vikings raided the monasteries to plunder all their riches and in the process they killed a large proportion of scholars.  As a result, when [King Ælfred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_the_Great) endeavoured to rekindle the light of English culture, he started writing texts in "Old Ænglisc" instead of Latin.  For this purpose he naturally used the Latin alphabet with however the addition of a few runic characters (among which the 'ð' and the 'þ' for the sound 'th').  The 'c' was used for the sound /k/, 'cw' for /kw/ (queen), 'ce' and 'ci' for [tʃ] (child) and 'sc' for [ʃ] (ship).  These conventions were inspired from Vulgar Latin.
4. In Middle English (in the wake of the Norman invasion), under the influence of the French spelling system, English underwent a spelling reform which affected many words containing the letter 'c'.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe it is the only one which changes from a "k"-sound to an "s"-sound when adding certain suffixes to the end of words like *electric* and *plastic*.

So if, say, *plastic* were changed to the more phonetically appropriate *plastik*, the derivation of *plasticity* would become (slightly) obscured, because, as far as I know, sounds represented by "k" at the end of a word never become "s", regardless of what sound comes after.

Such are the joys of the English alpha-, er, alfabet.

Comment: This is not technically a unique sound, but it is two unique behaviors with the same root spelling (and distinct k or s).  Accepted.

Comment: In fact, some relationships like this are already obscured with the current spelling system: *joke* is related to *jocular,* and *opaque* is related to *opacity.* More are described at [“Invoke” and “invocation”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37706/invoke-and-invocation)

Answer (score 4):

"C" is a letter and is used to make words. I am not sure what you are asking, here. A few thoughts:

- *watsh* could be pronounced differently from *watch*
- *chariot* has no appropriate substitute for the *ch* as *kh* would be very different
- *lock* and *black* are interesting in the sense that the *ck* is used instead of either *c* or *k*
- *scissor* likewise has *sc* instead of *s*

I remember seeing a list somewhere that pointed out the different behaviors of vowels near a *c*, *k*, *ck* or other variations. But in terms of 'C' technically serving a unique purpose, it certainly does *now* since it is the third letter of the alphabet and is used when writing hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: +1 for the nod to hexadecimal.  Of course, if we took it out, we'd just use A-G instead.

Comment: @Kit: That would cause some serious logistical issues... :P It would probably be "easier" to just replace the 'C' with a 'K' moving forward.

Comment: @MrHen But should we replace C with *K* or *S*?  What does a hexadecimal C sound like exactly?

Comment: I do not understand the difference between "watch" and "watsh" - if there is one, can you explain it?

Comment: +1 But forget hexadecimal, it's also a full-fledged programming language. With variants!

Comment: And besides hex, there is also music, where C is a note and a key.  That would really mess things up if the key of C were now the key of D, and the key of G were now the key of H.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek H minor could become the saddest of all keys.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek -- you can't introduce the key of H, the Germans already use it (to a German musician, B means B flat so they have to use H for what most of the rest of us call B). So it would have to be the key of I...

Comment: Couldn't *chariot* be spelled *tshariot* ?

Answer (score 3):

**[The Chaos](http://www.spellingsociety.org/journals/j17/caos.php)** by Gerard Nolst Trenité would seem obligatory.

> Dearest creature in creation
>   Studying English pronunciation,
>   I will teach you in my verse
>   Sounds like corpse, corps, horse and worse.
>
> I will keep you, Susy, busy,
>   Make your head with heat grow dizzy;
>   Tear in eye, your dress you'll tear;
>   Queer, fair seer, hear my prayer.
>
> Pray, console your loving poet,
>   Make my coat look new, dear, sew it!
>   Just compare heart, hear and heard,
>   Dies and diet, lord and word.
>
> Sword and sward, retain and Britain
>   (Mind the latter how it's written).
>   Made has not the sound of bade,
>   Say — said, pay — paid, laid but plaid.

Read the rest on the page behind the link. Here is part of the poem transcribed to the International Phonetic Alphabet:

[British pronunciation](http://www.madore.org/~david/misc/english-pronunciation.html) (which the poem was meant for):

> ˌdɪəɹɪst ˈkɹiːʧəɹ ɪn kɹɪ.ˈeɪʃn̩
>   ˌstʌdɪ.ɪŋ ˈɪŋɡlɪʃ pɹəˌnʌnsɪ.ˈeɪʃn̩
>   ˌaɪ wɪl ˈtiːʧ jʊ ɪn maɪ ˈvɜːs
>   ˈsaʊndz laɪk ˈkɔːps ˈkɔː ˈhɔːs ənd ˈwɜːs
>
> ˌaɪ wɪl ˈkiːp jʊ ˈsuːzɪ ˈbɪzɪ
>   ˌmeɪk jə ˈhɛd wɪð ˈhiːt ɡɹəʊ ˈdɪzɪ
>   ˈtɪəɹ ɪn ˌaɪ jə ˈdɹɛs wɪl ˈtɛə
>   ˈkwɪə ˌfɛə ˈsɪə ˈhɪə maɪ ˈpɹɛə
>
> ˈpɹeɪ kənˈsəʊl jə ˈlʌvɪŋ ˈpəʊ.ɪt
>   ˈmeɪk maɪ ˈkəʊt ˌlʊk ˈnjuː ˌdɪə ˈsəʊ ɪt
>   ˌʤʌst kəmˈpɛə ˈhɑːt ˈhɪəɹ ənd ˈhɜːd
>   ˈdaɪz ənd ˈdaɪ.ət ˈlɔːd ənd ˈwɜːd
>
> ˈsɔːd ənd ˈswɔːd ɹɪˈteɪn ənd ˈbɹɪtn̩
>   ˈmaɪnd ðə ˈlætə ˌhaʊ ɪts ˈɹɪtn̩
>   ˈmeɪd həz ˈnɒt ðə ˈsaʊnd əv ˈbæd
>   ˈseɪ ˈsɛd ˈpeɪ ˈpeɪd ˈleɪd bət ˈplæd

Comment: Or maybe just an excerpt?

Comment: @Callithumpian: Fine, fine... I just couldn't resist.

Comment: I understand (and didn't downvote, for the record).

Comment: @Callithumpian: Heh I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I think your case for *watch* -> *watsh* is mistaken.

The end of watch has a short *ch* sound. If I were drunk or particularly tired then I might pronounce it *wahsh*, but in trying to pronounce *watsh* in a normal state I end up practically ignoring the t all together.

Also, I find that if one tries to keep silent letters in mind when pronouncing words, then the pronunciation is distinct from if the letter were not there at all. So *science* sounds different (to me) to *sience*, for example.

Answer (score -1):

You've answered youself. *Ch* creates - among other pronunciations of this digraph - the sound *tsh'* which cannot be created otherwise. Like *cheese*, *China* and lots of other words. Sometimes it's used with *t* before, like in *watch*, *scotch* thus putting more stress on the *t* part of the sound.

Comment: I personally cannot hear a difference between the "ch" in "watch" as opposed to "china." I do not hear more of a "t" sound - what is the difference?

Comment: @user8809: Philoto is mistaken. There is no difference between them; both are /tʃ/.  Thus, "witch" and "which" are pronounced exactly the same: [wɪtʃ].  (Actually some Southern American dialects pronounce "which" as [ʍɪtʃ], but that is only a difference in the "w" sound, not the /tʃ/.)

Comment: @Kosmonaut On second thought yeah, there's no difference. Sometimes I tend to hear something where there's nothing to hear :)

Comment: You're not the only one; sometimes spelling can really affect speakers' perceptions of words.