# What is the process of letters changing, like c to k in invocation and invoked is called?

Tags: terminology

What is the process of letters changing called, like c to k in *invo**c**ation* and *invo**k**ed*? I am sure there are more examples of letters transforming. *Defen**c**e,* *defen**s**ive* would be another example (for people who don't use the spelling "defense").  I am leaving alone cases where the pronunciation changes as well, such as *advi**c**e* and *advi**s**or,* unless they are considered part of the same type of change.

Comment: Related: "[Why are nouns corresponding to verbs ending with “oke” written with “c”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284864)" It's not clear to me if the answer there is what you are looking for. Can you think of any other examples of what you're thinking of?

Comment: @suməlic : nope , but I have seen these switcheroos before with other alphabets, I come back with another such oddity

Comment: @suməlic : hell yes, c changing to s, yes I have seen that with other things as well

Comment: @suməlic : nop, I am leaving them alone! unless they are considered part of the same type of change. Maybe that can be a different question if it is only pronunciation, then we can also have a case of when both pronunciation and letter change as well.

Comment: @suməlic : thank you for the edit, much better than I could have made it.

Comment: I think it's called a "spelling change".  I think I saw that in a Spanish textbook.