# Why some words ending in -ke become -cable (and/or -cative), while others become -kable (or -keable)

Tags: orthography, suffixes, derivational-morphology

Today I learnt that revoke + able would make *revo**c**able*. What's the reasoning for this? Are there any other examples like this?

Comment: evoke / evocable etc; invoke / invocable etc; provoke / provocable etc. Not poke, smoke, yoke. Possibly just verbs ending -_voke_. But then there's joke / jocular.  But this is arguably off-topic, asking for a list. Though I won't close-vote, as in this case the list might be short and not unuseful.

Comment: the real question is: why does the K of verbs like revoke, provoke etc. turns into a c in the adjectival form?

Comment: @Hachi The words whose etymologies I've looked up and that are from the Latin all start off with the c. 'Poke' is Germanic in origin. But OP doesn't ask for etymologies of given word/s (which would trigger the 'research required' requirement).

Comment: I'm guessing this is for hysterical reasons.

Comment: I would upvote this question if you turned it into a question about why some words ending in -ke become -cable (and/or -cative), while others become -kable (or -keable). As Edwin Ashworth observes, there is a strong (and justified) bias against list request on this site—but the issue of differential ending change that you raise is interesting, especially if it turns out to be largely explicable in terms of the different language origins of the root words. (I would also change your tag from 'single-word-requests' to 'suffixes' and maybe 'orthography'.)

Comment: This is not a question about English, but about the vagaries of English spelling. Sounds don't come from letters -- letters come from sounds.

Comment: @JohnLawler -          How are vagaries of English spelling not about English?

Comment: Because they don't have any relation to the English language, only to the technology for recording it, which simply piles up changes like Windows versions, all following different rules, none of which refer to the language.

Comment: Normally when you turn C to K you've got to add 273.15.  Turning C to F is a hair more complicated.

Comment: @SvenYargs I updated the question based on your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Whatever reasons there might be for this question being off-topic, being about English spelling isn't among them. This site's scope includes English language -- there is no restriction to spoken English. And to call writing "only ... the technology for recording it" sells it woefully short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Latin vs Germanic origin.

Consider the following examples:

*Likeable, unlikeable, makeable* - **Germanic origin**

These words are of Germanic origin. And German allow 'k' in suffixed words.

On the other hand,

*Revocable, invocable, provocable* - **Latin origin**

These words are derived from Latin *revocare, invocare* and *provocare* respectively.

In Latin, they're pronounced with /k/ sound (it's obvious from the spelling - 'care', *c* often gives /k/ sound when it precedes 'e').

These words are anglicised to *revoke, invoke* and *provoke*.

**Where did the k come from:**
In order to maintain the /k/ sound (which is in the original pronunciation 'care'), the 'ce' was changed to 'ke'. Because if it were written as 'revoce' it would be pronounced with /s/ sound rather than the original /k/ sound.

Hachi's comment:

> The real question is: why does the K of verbs like revoke, provoke etc. turns into a c in the adjectival form?

When a suffix is added to *revoke*, the 'k' changes to 'c' because it's not allowed in Latin (and Latin words in English) to have 'k' in suffixed words. Latin does not allow the letter 'k' at all.

Therefore, **revoke** + **able** -> **revo(_)able**/ **revoke** + **tion** -> **revocation** ---> 'k' is not allowed, we need another letter than gives /k/ sound (original sound) before the letter 'a' - the only letter (other than 'k' because 'k' is not allowed) that gives /k/ sound before 'a' is *c*.

- Revoke + able -> revo**ca**ble.
- Invoke + able -> invo**ca**ble
- Provoke + able -> provo**ca**ble

However, 'notice' is also from Latin but it does not have the letter 'k' because the original pronunciation (in Latin) has /s/ sound rather than /k/ sound. In order to maintain the original sound, we write 'notice' with *c* sound because 'c' often gives /s/ sound when it precedes *e*.

Notice + able -> noti**cea**ble not noti**ca**ble because it changes the original pronunciation of the base word.

<sup>Why doesn't Latin allow the letter k: [Lewis and Short](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=k&filter=CUTF8) also have a look at [Latin SE](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/does-latin-allow-the-letter-k-in-suffixed-words/13867?noredirect=1#comment26372_13867)</sup>

<sup><sub>I found another [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284864/why-do-verbs-end-with-oke-while-their-corresponding-nouns-are-written-with-c) but the answers there do not address the 'why'.</sub></sup>

Comment: This is broadly right, but I'd quibble over some details. The forms with 'c', like _revocable_ and _vocation_ are mostly borrowed from French or Latin, rather than being formed in English, so they came with a 'c'. The outlier is the verb form with 'k', which has been remodelled in English, as you say, apparently to avoid the 'oce' spelling. So it's not English using 'c' instead of 'k'; it's English not changing 'c' to 'k' in those contexts. _Notice_ is quite different because it was remodelled in French: the Latin word is _notitia_, which has neither 'c' nor 'k'

Comment: "it's not allowed in Latin (and Latin words in English) to have 'k' in suffixed words." Then why do we have "embark" and "embarkation"?

Comment: I personally think "ka" should be written throughout Latin instead of "ca". "c" should instead use the /t͜ʃ/ phoneme everywhere as there is no letter to write that phoneme.

Comment: Why does "remarkable" use "k" even though it is of Latin origin?